# verbatim font in align environment

Tags: align, verbatim

Is it possible to use the font of verbatim environment in align environment, please? I need to do so for a block of coding which is mathematic formulae itself. Thanks. If you like an example, please see below. In that picture, I wount like to combine the effect of align and verbatim.

[image: I want to combine the effect of align and verbatim]

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
a &= b+1 \\
  &= c+2
\end{align*}

\begin{verbatim}
a = b+1
  = c+2
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Comment: With `\texttt{formula}`?

Comment: Can you make a minimal example of what you need?

Comment: @egreg Please see my update.

Comment: @Arzigoglu I tried your suggestion, but it did not seem to work.

Comment: Inside of `align` you could use `\mathtt{formula}`

Answer (score 3):

The following works <strike>but gives ugly spacing</strike> (Thanks to Steven B. Segletes):

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \mathtt{a}&\mathtt{{}=b+1}\\%insert {} before = to get the spacing right
    &\mathtt{{}=c+2}
    \label{ha}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another solution -- which I wouldn't use because it alters too much:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault}% has to be used before mathastext
\usepackage{mathastext}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\rmdefault}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    a&=b+1\\
     &=c+2
    \label{ha}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To allow the font changes to be switched on and off, one can use the `subdued`-option of `mathastext`. Please note, that this does NOT leave the default math versions untouched! Read the [package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathastext/mathastext.pdf) and specifically the section dealing with subdued (1.3.3 as of writing this) for more information!

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[subdued,defaultmathsizes,defaultimath,nohbar]{mathastext}
\MTDeclareVersion[n]{lmvtt}{T1}{lmvtt}{m}{n}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault}% has to be used before mathastext
\Mathastext[ttmath]
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\rmdefault}
\begin{document}
normal:
\begin{align}
    a&=b+1\\
     &=c+2
    \label{ha}
\end{align}
\bgroup
tt-style:
\MTversion{ttmath}
\begin{align}
    a&=b+1\\
     &=c+2
    \label{hatt}
\end{align}
\egroup
normal:
\begin{align}
    a&=b+1\\
     &=c+2
    \label{haha}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Let alone that you need to type mathtt all the time.

Comment: Another complication is that I only want to use verbatim font in certain align environment but not all. So the second method might not work.

Comment: @LaTeXFan Please see my edit!

Comment: You can fix the first method by adding a blank atom to the left of the `=`, as in `\mathtt{{}=b+1}`.  Likewise, `\mathtt{{}=c+2}`